# How to use Appium with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, appium

I'm trying to use Appium with Android Studio. My search on google doesn't helped much out!
So what do I need in the gradle file and how to run the tests?

Thanks

Comment: Check their github to find the gradle dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle file should be like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    Mention all your jar here
}
```

From command line you can run your gradle(gradle assemble) to create the jar of your test and then you can run that jar.

Comment: In dependencies I have  androidTestCompile 'io.appium:java-client:2.0.0' . Do I have to add an appium.jar file to my build path? I know that junit and robotium need some.

Comment: i don't think you need to add appium.jar but when you compile it, you will see the error for the missing Jar files.